# Python split() method removes not only whitespaces

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, split

While working on a problem I accidentally noticed that Python str.split() method without any parameters removes not only whitespaces as described in its [latest official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/stdtypes.html#text-sequence-type-str), but it also removes `'\n'` that is placed anywhere in the string.

For example, suppose I want to split the following string `' a b  c   d \n '` using `.split()` without any parameters. The expected output according to the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) is the following list: `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', '\n']` , however, you get the following:  `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']` .

The same is true no matter whether `'\n'` is at the end, in the beginning or inside the string.

I could not find anywhere mentioning this property of `str.split()` , thus I have a question: Is this behavior reliable and will it always do the same in any circumstance or is it just some kind of luckiness here?

I am running Python 3.10.8

Comment: From your linked manual entry: *If sep is not specified or is None, a different splitting algorithm is applied: runs of consecutive **whitespace** are regarded as a single separator, and the result will contain no empty strings at the start or end if the string has leading or trailing whitespace. Consequently, splitting an empty string or a string consisting of just whitespace with a None separator returns [].* (Tabs, newlines, carriage returns, etc, are all types of 'whitespace')

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are misreading the documentation you linked to. The term "whitespace" *includes* the newline character. From the documentation for Python's `str.isspace()`:

> A character is whitespace if in the Unicode character database (see `unicodedata`), either its general category is `Zs` ("Separator, space"), or its bidirectional class is one of `WS`, `B`, or `S`.

From the [Unicode entry](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+000A), you can see the category is `Cc` (control) but the bidirectional class is `B` (paragraph separator), so it's covered by the whitespace definition quoted above (`WS` is Unicode whitespace, a subset of Python whitepace, and `S` is segment separator).

The following transcript shows that the newline is indeed in that whitespace class:

```py
>>> "\n".isspace()
True
```

The full list can be obtained with the `string.whitespace` constant:

```py
>>> import string
>>> string.whitespace
' \t\n\r\x0b\x0c'
```

So it includes space, tab, newline, carriage return, vertical tab, and form feed.

Comment: To check what Python thinks is a whitespace, you can ask to the string module: `import string` + `string.whitespace` -> `' \t\n\r\x0b\x0c'`

Comment: Thanks, @Hrabal, incorporated that into the answer.

Answer (score 0):

i think you are not getting it it's not removing the \n it's working fine